# How to convert a jsonobject into a jsonarray and also change all keys with all custom same keys in Java and Android

Tags: java, arrays, json, android-studio, android-recyclerview

### Code:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray.length(); j++) {
    JSONObject list = jsonArray.getJSONObject(j);

    String key = list.getString("symbol") + list.getString("groupname");

    if (!map.containsKey(key)) {
        map.put(key, list.getInt("openqty"));

    } else {
        int val = map.get(key) + list.getInt("openqty");
        map.put(key, val);
    }

    System.out.println("map " + map);
}

// Converted map into jsonstring
String jsonString = new JSONObject(map).toString();
System.out.println("jsonstring " + jsonString);
```

---

**Output:**

```
     {"SILVERRohit":0,"DINRCosmic":20,"NATURALGASCosmic":0,"NGCosmic":0,"SICosmic":-5,"SILVERCosmic":35,"DINRRishi":0,"SIRishi":0,"SILVERRishi":0,"CLAmitTA":-6,
"CRUDEOILAmitTA":60,"DINRAmitTA":24,"GCAmitTA":0,"GOLDAmitTA":0,"SIAmitTA":0,"SILVERAmitTA":0,"DINRPraveen":0,"GCPraveen":0,"GOLDPraveen":0,"DINRHarsh":46,
"GCHarsh":-9,"GOLDHarsh":28,"SIHarsh":9,"SILVERHarsh":-45,"DINRGovind":-160,"SIGovind":11}
```

^^ this is an jsonobject I have got by using linkedhashmap. So, now my problem is I want to convert it into jsonArray format to set in the model (recyclerview). I have also tried by iterating, but I am getting the same values in each single row.

Not only this, but also I want to change all jsonobject keys to "open", so that I can use this in recyclerview for each single row.

**Expected output:**

```
[    {"open":0},{"open":20} , {"open":0} ,   {"open":0} ,{"open":-5 } ,
 {"open":35 } , {"open":0} ,{"open":0 },{"open":0 } ,{"open":-6 },
 {"open":60},{"open":24},{"open":0},{"open":0},{"open":0},
{"open":0},{"open":0},{"open":0},{"open":0},{"open":46},
{"open":-9},{"open":28},{"open":9},{"open":-45},
{"open":-160},{"open":11}    ]
```

Comment: as we have json string :    {"SILVERRohit":0,"DINRCosmic":20,"NATURALGASCosmic":0 }   
 first make this into   [ {"SILVERRohit":0} , {"DINRCosmic":20} , {"NATURALGASCosmic":0}  ]  then finally i want to replace all keys with same key -  [ {"open":0} , {"open":20} , {"open":0}  ] if is it possible guys. please help me .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As you got the hashmap, iterate the map like this:

```html
Map<String,String> data = MapUtil.newHashMap();
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : data.entrySet()) {
    Map<String,String> json = MapUtil.newHashMap();
    json.put("open", entry.getValue());
    jsonArray.add(json);
}
return jsonArray;
```

Comment: thanks sir got output but  how to remove Double quotes  please help : ["{open=0}","{open=0}","{open=0}","{open=-45}","{open=-140}","{open=15}","{open=132}","{open=-19}","{open=57}","{open=0}","{open=0}","{open=0}","{open=-25}","{open=250}","{open=95}","{open=0}","{open=0}","{open=1}","{open=-5}","{open=0}","{open=0}","{open=0}","{open=5}","{open=-25}","{open=-390}","{open=75}"]

Comment: removed double quotes by using regular expression  but cant  able to convert it into json format  : [{open=0},{open=-45},{open=-150},{open=15},{open=147},{open=-24},{open=72},{open=-96},{open=24},{open=-116},{open=-25},{open=250},{open=102},{open=-1},{open=3},{open=2},{open=-10},{open=-9},{open=-5},{open=15},{open=11},{open=-56},{open=-34},{open=25},{open=-125},{open=-10},{open=30},{open=10},{open=-50},{open=-234},{open=21}]

Comment: done . output : 2022-06-29 10:18:26.228 7951-7951/com.example.m I/System.out: jsonstring [{"open":0},{"open":-45},{"open":-150},{"open":15},{"open":147},{"open":-24},{"open":72},{"open":-96},{"open":24},{"open":-116},{"open":-25},{"open":250},{"open":102},{"open":-1},{"open":3},{"open":2},{"open":-10},{"open":-9},{"open":-5},{"open":15},{"open":11},{"open":-56},{"open":-34},{"open":25},{"open":-125},{"open":-10},{"open":30},{"open":10},{"open":-50},{"open":-234},{"open":21}]

Comment: Some related meta posts: *[Should it be more obvious that stack snippets are only meant for HTML/CSS/JS?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277602/)*, *[Abusing the Code Snippet for wrong languages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283108/)*, *[How can we keep people from using 'JavaScript/ HTML/ CSS snippet' option with other languages?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375023/)*, and *[How to use "code snippet" vs "code block"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367517/)*

Comment: The sample code is in [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29). Code snippets are ***only*** for [JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) (and perhaps HTML and CSS). Please [do](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72782269/edit) the needful. Thanks in advance.